# Geometry problem

Tags: geometry

consider ΔXYZ be a triangle with YZ=5, XY=6 and XZ=7. Let C be the circumcentre of ΔXYZ, $C_y$ and $C_z$ be the reflection of C about lines XZ and XY respectively. Suppose the lines $YC_y$ and $ZC_z$ intersect at A and B is the midpoint of YZ then  find the length of AB and area of triangle $XC_{y}C_{z}$.

I tried using a little geometry and found the distance CB to be $$5/4√6$$ but couldn't get a hint to find length AB

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Introduce a  system of $xy$ coordinates.

$X=(0,0),\;Y=(6,0)$

Coordinates of $Z$ can be found solving the system between the equation of the circle having centre in $X$ and radius $7$ and circle with centre $Y$ and radius $5$

$
\left\{
\begin{array}{l}
 x^2+y^2=49 \\
 (x-6)^2+y^2=25 \\
\end{array}
\right.
$

which gives $Z=(5;\;2\sqrt 6)$

Then, to find the circumcentre coordinates we consider the system between the perpendicular bisector of $XY$ which has equation $x=3$ and the perpendicular bisector of $XZ$ which is

$x^2+y^2=(5-x)^2+\left(y-2 \sqrt{6}\right)^2$

simplified $y= \dfrac{49}{4 \sqrt{6}}-\dfrac{5 x}{2 \sqrt{6}}$

plug $x=3$ and get $y=\dfrac{19}{4 \sqrt{6}}$

so we have $C=\left(3;\;\dfrac{19}{4 \sqrt{6}}\right)$

the distance $XC=\dfrac{1225}{96}$ is the radius

Coordinates of $C_z$ are $C_z=\left(3;\;-\dfrac{19}{4 \sqrt{6}}\right)$ because $C_z$ is the symmetric of $C$ wrt the $x-$axis

To find $C_y$ we write the equation of $XZ$ that is $y=\dfrac{2 \sqrt{6} x}{5}$ and consider $C_y=(p;q)$ such that

- midpoint of $CC_y$ is on $XZ$ which means $\frac{1}{2} \left(q+\frac{19}{4 \sqrt{6}}\right)=\frac{1}{5} \sqrt{6} (p+3)$
- $CC_y$ is perpendicular to $XZ$ which means $\dfrac{\left(2 \sqrt{6}\right) \left(q-\frac{19}{4 \sqrt{6}}\right)}{5 (p-3)}=-1$

Solving the system we get $C_y=\left(2,\frac{29}{4 \sqrt{6}}\right)$

The coordinates of $A$ can be found solving the system between the lines $YC_y$ and ZC_z$ that is

$
\left\{
\begin{array}{l}
 y-\frac{19}{4 \sqrt{6}}=\frac{67 (x-3)}{8 \sqrt{6}} \\
 y=-\frac{29 (x-6)}{16 \sqrt{6}} \\
\end{array}
\right.
$

and we get $A=\left(4;\;\frac{29}{8 \sqrt{6}}\right)$

Coordinates of $B$ are $B=\left(\frac{11}{2};\;\sqrt 6\right)$

Thus $AB=\sqrt{\left(\frac{11}{2}-4\right)^2+\left(\sqrt 6-\frac{29}{8 \sqrt{6}}\right)^2}=\dfrac{35}{8 \sqrt{6}}$

Finally the area of the triangle $XC_yC_z$

We have the length of the sides

$XC_y=XC_z=\frac{35}{4 \sqrt{6}};\;C_yC_z=5$

The triangle is isosceles the height is, by Pythagoras theorem

$h=\sqrt{\left(\frac{35}{4 \sqrt{6}}\right)^2-\left(\frac{5}{2}\right)^2}=\dfrac{25}{4 \sqrt{6}}$

So the area is $Area_{XC_yC_z}=\frac{5\cdot \dfrac{25}{4 \sqrt{6}}}{2}=\dfrac{125}{8 \sqrt{6}}$

Hope this is useful

[image]

Comment: Brilliantly answered.  Thanks for your help.